# jQuery Sortable problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

In my users/index view that holds the unordered list

```
<ul id="documents" data-update-url="<%= sort_documents_url %>">
  <% @documents.each do |document| %>
  <%= content_tag_for :li, document do %>
  <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
  <%= link_to h(document.title), document %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', document, method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

As you see inside the the ul I am rendering a partial for each model.
The _documents.html.erb partial
2nd Update of rendered html.

```
<ul id="documents" data-update-url="http://localhost:3000/documents/sort">
  <li class="document" id="document_4fc4db0cb6231417f300000c">
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db0cb6231417f300000c">Help</a>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db0cb6231417f300000c" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
</li>  <li class="document" id="document_4fc4db27b6231417f300000f">
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db27b6231417f300000f">adam</a>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db27b6231417f300000f" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
</li>  <li class="document" id="document_4fc4db2db6231417f3000010">
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db2db6231417f3000010">adam</a>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4db2db6231417f3000010" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
</li>  <li class="document" id="document_4fc4dbaab6231417f3000015">
    <span class="handle">[drag]</span>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4dbaab6231417f3000015"></a>
    <a href="/documents/4fc4dbaab6231417f3000015" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Delete</a>
</li></ul>
```

document.js.coffee
jQuery ->

```
  $('#documents').sortable
    handle: '.handle'
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
```

Comment: Instead of posting the Ruby template, post the rendered HTML instead. JavaScript is like the [honey badger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg): JavaScript don't care about your Ruby; JavaScript don't give a s***!

Comment: There should be no <div> in a <ul>, only <li>s.

Comment: So what is the actual problem? You (now) have a proper `<ul>`, some CoffeeScript (which we can't see), and something happens but that *something* isn't what you're expecting. What does your CoffeeScript look like? What are expecting to happen? What does happen?

Comment: I'm trying to add sorting functionality to a list., added my coffee script.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CoffeeScript, but any chance you can post the rendered JavaScript too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `<div>` directly under a `<ul>`. I bet that's throwing off the script.

In fact, [you cannot have anything other than `<li>` inside a `<ol>` or `<ul>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element)

Comment: so use span instead to style my li elements?

Comment: No, just use the `<li>` element. You don't need to wrap it in anything. In CSS, `ul#sortable li .stuff` is perfectly OK.

Comment: I got it, thanks, I've done what you've said but still getting no sort. have updated

Comment: Marking this answered because that was the underlying problem, eventually my rails assets got updated and i can sort now :)